# Stock price and volume derivative at time t

Tags: python, volume, price, derivative

According to [Forecasting of Jump Arrivals in Stock Prices: New Attention-based Network Architecture using Limit Order Book Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.10845) at page 9, I would be interested in derivating the the price and volume, but I am struggling how to do it. So far I tried nothing, because I just don't know where to start and how to do it.

How can I derive the price and the volume with python?

Comment: What have you tried? show us your code

Comment: @VegardKT  So far I tried nothing, because I just don't know where to start and how to do it.

Comment: Then this is all i can do to help.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative

Try first, ask questions later

Comment: Cross-posted in https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43970/derivative-of-the-stock-price-and-volume-at-time-t. I think you’d increase the chance of getting an answer by limiting your question to one of either the algorithm or the implementation. Asking both likely leads to none of the communities answering it.